# 2 Vectors, 4 dimension, the cross-product

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, cross-product

As one of the requirements for my course, we were given a task to answer which is determining the cross product of the given: U = (1, -4, 5, 7)         V =(1, 2, 6, 7)

I've already searched tons of forums and most of them answer that this is not possible. Yet I wish to provide solid proof and arguments as I present my answer to my professor. Your help would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What exactly does your professor mean by the cross product of two vectors?

Comment: @Manx:  that’s the _dot_ product

Comment: Note that the cross product is only defined for vector spaces of 3 and 7 dimensions, (as well as the pretend 2D case)

Answer (score 1):

Note that both of your vectors have $7$ as the forth component. So you can `ignore' the fourth component for a moment and find the cross product of $(1,-4,5)$ and $v=(1,2,6)$ which for that order is $(-10,5,6)$. So if for the cross product you want a vector perpendicular to both $u,v$, you can take $(-10,5,6,0)$.
This is a vector is certainly perpendicular to the plane spanned by $u,v$.

If instead of $7$ the fourth component was $0$, we could find infinitely many $4$ tuples orthogonal to $u,v$ unless we impose some extra condition.

So the question then is what the person who wrote the question meant by this exactly.